# User Mode Virtual Midi Cable Driver

Tags: driver, midi, umdf

I 'm looking for a way to create a user mode virtual midi cable driver.

Unfortunately there's nothing at MSDN, and in the MSDN forums I asked nobody is sure about how it should be implemented.

First, is it possible?

Second, I 'm not sure if the information at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is applicable to UMDF.

Anyone that has more clues than I have?

Update: This guy here https://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/virtualmidisynth has created it, so there must be a user mode way.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is (unfortunately) a rather difficult task to accomplish in Windows. Your best bet is to use [MIDIOX's Yoke Junction](http://www.midiox.com/index.htm?http://www.midiox.com/myoke.htm) to create a virtual device to communicate through.

Comment: Well difficult or not it doesn't matter. The point is how it can be done.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis did you find a solution? I've been Googling for days to no avail.